# Что такое pause on caught exeptions?

Tags: javascript, отладка, google-chrome-devtools

Как я понимаю, кнопка **pause on exeptions** позволяет остановить выполнения кода до появления строки с ошибкой в консоли.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если с **pause on exeptions** что-то более-менее ясно, то что делает **pause on caught exeptions** ("пауза при обработанных исключениях", если перевести) вообще не понятно. Что такое эти обработанные исключения?

Comment: Возможно, исключения, попадающие в [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

Comment: @vsemozhebuty хм, непонятно как-то. А вы вообще этим `pause on caught exeptions`  часто пользуетесь?

Comment: Я нет)..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы понять разницу, попробуйте запустить этот код с галочкой и без. Без галочки паузы не будет, потому что исключение было обработано. С галочкой пауза будет.

```js
'use strict';

try {
  nonExistentFunction();
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.message);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То есть получается, что `pause on caught exceptions` работает только при использовании конструкции `try...catch`? В "обычном" коде я не вижу никакого эффекта

Comment: Думаю, да......